# Using an array as a subindex of a larger dimension array

Tags: r, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays: P and arr, whose dimension are:

```
> dim(arr)
[1] 8 2

> dim(P)
[1] 3 8 2
```

Then, arr has values

```
> arr
      [,1][,2]
[1,]    2    1
[2,]    1    2
[3,]    1    3
[4,]    1    4
[5,]    2    5
[6,]    2    6
[7,]    2    7
[8,]    2    8
```

which are intended to be a subindex of the P matrix. So, what I'd like to do is something like this

```
P[1,arr]
```

to obtain the values

```
P[1,2,1]
P[1,1,2]
P[1,1,3]
...
P[1,2,8]
```

, but P[1,arr] gives the error

```
Error in P[1, arr] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

How can I use arr as a subindex of P?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `cbind` to create the indexing matrix:

```
P[cbind(1, arr)]
```

though note you may need to change the column order of `arr` so that the second column comes first since your second dimension is the one with 8 possible values.  So maybe:

```
P[cbind(1, arr[, 2:1])]
```